# How many rows in a mysql BEFORE fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting some data from the mysql through a select.

```
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query);
```

I then go through it with

```
if ($result!= false) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        do_stuff();
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to add a line before the `while` ONLY if there is more than one line in the $result.

I understand that I could create an array of `$row`'s first and then count them, but that would defeat the convenience of the `while`.

Question: is there a way to find out how many rows the mysqli_fetch_assoc would generate without running it twice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should check this function: http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows

You can check the number of results by using it like this

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
..
}
```

Comment: love this place. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

use http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows which returns count of rows in result

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1)
```